# how to mask/disable the whole page regardelss of what componenets are inside

Tags: reactjs

I know how to disable components separately, for instance how to do it for an `<input />` or a `<button />`.

But I need something else, at some points in my app (for instance while I'm loading some stuff) I need the **whole** page to be masked so that nothing will work no clicking no typing nothing and if the color gets blurred that's even better. 
AS I mentioned I can do that for all components separately but I need something that regardless of what is in the page just mask/disable all the page till my loading is done and i turn it back.

I tried  `<fieldset disabled>`  but it doesn't do it for the whole page, for instance buttons.

Comment: The way I achieved this was by having an 'enabled' state property in my controlling class.  This 'enable' state property is switched whilst loading takes place.  I also pass 'enabled' to each of the components for the page.  In each component, I handle the enabled value as appropriate.  As I use setState for 'enabled' in the controlling class, each update is passed to each child component.

Comment: @ChrisAdams  thanks but you say ` I also pass 'enabled' to each of the components ` as i mentioned i need to be done regardless of the children so something that i add to the main tag for instance the main div and then it masked the whole page

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was to set `style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}` and then when the load is done change it to `auto`